# Ruby: undefined method `find_by_username'

Tags: html, ruby, erb

I've been following a tutorial [Follower Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bfuiil0qP3c) and I keep getting the error undefined method `find_by_username' for the line.

```
<%= render '/components/follow_button', :user => User.find_by_username(params[:id]) %>
```

show.html.erb

```
    <%= render '/components/follow_button', :user => User.find_by_username(params[:id]) %>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-body">
                 <h5 style="color: grey; font-size: 125%;">Who to follow</h5>
                 <% for @u in @toFollow do %>
                   <p style="font-weight: bold; opacity: 0.85;" ><a href="/user/<%= @u.username %>"><%= @u.username %></a></p>
                 <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
```

user.rb

```
  def unfollow(other)
active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other.id).destroy
```

_follow_button.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.id != user.id %>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <center>
            <% if !current_user.following?(user) %>
                <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build) do |f| %>
                    <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, user.id %></div>
                    <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                <% end %>
            <% else %>
                <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id),
                    html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
                    <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn" %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been messing around for ages now and can't work it out. Any help would be appreciated. Feel free to ask for more code etc.

Comment: Can you post schema/migration file for `User` model?

Comment: Note that you are trying to find a user based on the username but you are passing in an id ``User.find_by_username(params[:id]``. This is probably not the cause of your error though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In newer version of rails you should use following code:

Inside controller:

```
@user = User.find_by(username: username)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4 onwards the `find_by_...` methods are deprecated therefore your `User.find_by_username` will not work for Rails 4 and higher. You should be able to use either:

```
User.find(id)
```

or

```
User.where(:username=> username)
```